# django_heroku.settings(locals()) not at the end for collectstatic

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku, static

I created an webapp with Django, heroku and S3.
In production it seems that the upload of static files are only working when comment out django_heroku.settings(locals())

```
#django_heroku.settings(locals())

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Then in the HTML, the urls to the static files do either get an encryption in the name like "main.css" becomes "main-5354332324.css", and cant get access, or I add

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

and the names of the static file stay but still can't be accessed.

So far I understand that django_heroku.settings(locals()) would overwrite locations with a default value. I was wondering what exactly happens here and what is an appropriates solution for production, as django_heroku.settings(locals()) should be actually at the end and it should be AWS_DEFAULT_ACL=None as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

hey I had the same problem django_heroku overwrites whatever you have using whitenoise and saving it to staticfiles what i did was add  this line at the bottom of my code `django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)` add your config vars to heroku either from the cli or app settings

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem, when I put `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in `settings.py` module. It worked after modifying the line to `django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)`.